# Screen recording: stop failed and Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android

I can't succeed in screen recording, it starts recording ok but when it stops app crashes

the error:

> E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.confusedbox.screenrecorder, PID: 6314 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000,
>   result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.confusedbox.screenrecorder/com.confusedbox.screenrecorder.ScreenRecord}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3706)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3749)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:153)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
>       at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
>       at com.confusedbox.screenrecorder.ScreenRecord.onActivityResult(ScreenRecord.java:48)
>       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6508)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3702)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3749) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:153) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)

```
public class ScreenRecord extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaRecorder mr;
    MediaProjection mp;
    int dw = 720;
    int dh = 1280;
    MediaProjectionManager mpm;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mr = new MediaRecorder();
        initRecorder();
        mpm = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        startActivityForResult(mpm.createScreenCaptureIntent(), 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mp = mpm.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mp.createVirtualDisplay(getClass().getName(), dw, dh, metrics.densityDpi,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mr.getSurface(), 
                null, null);
        mr.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        mr.stop();
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        try {
            mr.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mr.setOutputFile(Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                            .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/video.mp4");
            mr.setVideoSize(dw, dh);
            mr.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mr.setVideoEncodingBitRate(12 * 1000 * 1000);
            mr.setVideoFrameRate(60);
            mr.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Android 6 (Marshmallow)

Comment: Having the exact same issue now, did you ever find a solution to mMediaRecorder.stop(); crash 'E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007' ?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `stop()` to some other place, after you are sure that the recording has actually started. My guess is that `start()` does not take effect until sometime after you return control of the main application thread to Android.

Comment: I tried `mHandler = new Handler();` in `onCreate`, `mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mr.stop();
            }
        }, 30000);` - 30 sec and it still throws `stop failed: -1007`

Comment: @user924: Check LogCat for recording errors (e.g., you lack `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and its runtime permission). See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/MediaProjection/andcorder) for a demonstration of recording a screencast.

Comment: I have all needed permissions (just didn't include it in this example) and it actually creates video file on the sdcard which can't be played (3kb)

Comment: @user924: Your recording type (`THREE_GPP`) does not match your file extension, and I do not know whether it is supported by the media projection APIs.

Comment: no difference when I set `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4`

Comment: @user924: Then compare and contrast the rest of your setup with what I have in [the sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/MediaProjection/andcorder).

Comment: I just want to run this sample app (before reading the code) and test if it works, but what does it do? Does it start recording when I run app (in the service) or what? when it stops and where I can find the videofile?

Comment: @user924: It displays a `Notification` with actions to control recording. You can also start and stop recording from the command line of the developer machine. The sample app is covered in detail in [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android); here is [a preview of the chapter on the media projection APIs](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/the-media-projection-apis).

Comment: No action buttons in the notification, just icon of the app

Comment: @user924: The service sets up a `Notification` [with two actions](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.6/MediaProjection/andcorder/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andcorder/RecorderService.java#L94-L126).

Comment: @user924: Try a two-finger swipe gesture or something. I don't know your device and what is required to make action buttons appear.

Comment: they usually already appeared for other apps, here screenshot of notification with action buttons for other app: https://postimg.org/image/su38kufex/ I don't know for this sample notification actions don't work